# Jquery cookie only on one site active

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, plugins

Hi there i am using the jquery cookie plugin in this context:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.close').click(function(){
    var user = $('div.popup div.user_information').html();

    $.cookie('the_cookie', user, {expires: "7",path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
    message = $.cookie('the_cookie');

    $('div.last_seen').html(message);
  });
});
```

When i click the "a.close" the cookie works correctly and the html of "div.user_information" is saved in the cookie and displayed in the html-element "div.last_seen".

The current url is:

> domain.com/test/index.php#close

But when i refresh to this site:

> domain.com/test/index.php

It seems the cookie session ends and so the content of "the div.last_seen" disappear´s as well.

Anybody knows why?

Greetings and thanks!!

WORKS WITH THIS CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.close').click(function(){
        var user = $('div.popup div.user').html();
        $.cookie('the_cookie', user, {expires: 7, path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
        var message = $.cookie('the_cookie');
        $('div.last_seen').html(message);
    });
    var message = $.cookie('the_cookie');
    $('div.last_seen').html(message);
});
```

Comment: when do you want the cookie to expire?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I missed a very crucial point; the problem lies with the fact that you never actually load the cookie and change the HTML when the DOM is loaded, you only do that after the button is clicked. Try copying this piece of code and placing it outside of your `.click()` function:

```
message = $.cookie('the_cookie');

$('div.last_seen').html(message);
```

In addition...

Looks like your value for the `expires` attribute is a String, not an integer like the API suggests it should be. Try removing the quotes around your `expires` value of 7 to get:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', user, {expires: 7, path: "/"});
```

NOTE: There is no reason to set the `domain` value in the options if the domain is the same as where the cookie is created, as in this example. ([see this link](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#domain))

**EDIT 2:** In response to the comment asking about storing multiple values, just store a JavaScript object instead of a String. Try something like this:

```
var myCookie = {};
myCookie['user'] = $('div.popup div.user_information').html();
myCookie['otherValue'] = "some other value...";

$.cookie('the_cookie', myCookie, {expires: 7,path: "/"});
```

Then to access those values from the cookie you get, do something like this:

```
var myCookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
var message = myCookie.user;   // or you could use myCookie['user']
var otherValue = myCookie.otherValue;   // likewise, myCookie['otherValue'] is ok

$('div.last_seen').html(message);
```

Comment: The user-information should be saved when the popup closes, so how can i paste the cookie out of the click-event?

Comment: Keep your click event code the same. You are saying the cookie's information is not loaded when you _refresh the page_. This is because the two lines of code I provided need to _also_ be outside of the click event (AKA when the DOM is loaded and ready) so the value can be updated when the page loads.

Comment: ok but this src : "domain.com/test/index.php#close" is not the same as : "domain.com/test/index.php" ? ,ok and what should i put for domain, when the cookie should work on every site of the domain? greetings

Comment: You don't need to specify domain at all. It defaults automatically to where the cookie was created from (in this case, it defaults to `domain.com`). You can still specify it if you want to, but that would be unnecessary.

Comment: ah ok thanks it works with the code aboth! :)  One more question, is it possible to more more than one value in one cookie or do i have to create a cookie for every value?

Comment: Yep, you can. Check my second edit I made to my answer.

Comment: ok but then i get :TypeError: options.expires.toUTCString is not a function" , sure about it?

Comment: Whoops, I copied your code from your original post, which had the `expires` value set to a String, not a number. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the cookie was not called after the page loads. It just save the div's content, but you don't call it when the page refreshes.

```
<pre><code>
    var cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
</code></pre>
```

Comment: shall i add this snippet in my html at beginning?

Comment: In the jQuery definition: $(document).ready(function(){ Just like the click event.